# Looping through the "choices" for a quiz item

Tags: javascript

I have the making of a quiz and my question is how can I loop through the choices to give me a proper looking quiz question with the question on top and the choices beneath it with a radio button preceding each choice. My HTML5 and javascript is below. Thank you.

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">

        <script>
            function Question(q, choices, answer) {
                this.question = q;
                this.choices = choices;
                this.correctAnswer = answer;
            }
        </script>


    </head>

    <body>

        <p id="demo"></p>
        <p id="demo2"></p>

        <script>
        var ques1 = new Question("What is the capital of PA?", "Erie,Pittsburgh,Harrisburg","Harrisburg");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ques1.question;
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = ques1.choices;
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is working for you ?

Answer (score 0):

First split string of choices into array

```
var choices = ques1.choices.split(',');
```

Then iterate throug array

```
choices.forEach(function(element, key) {
    // do somethinf with element
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const htmlOfChoices= ques1.choices.split(',').map(
   choice => `<span><input type="radio" name="q1" value="${choice}" />${choice}</span>`
).join('<br />');

document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = htmlOfChoices
```

### Demo below

```js
function Question(q, choices, answer) {
    this.question = q;
    this.choices = choices;
    this.correctAnswer = answer;
}

var ques1 = new Question("What is the capital of PA?", "Erie,Pittsburgh,Harrisburg","Harrisburg");


document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ques1.question;


const htmlOfChoices= ques1.choices.split(',').map(
   choice => `<span><input type="radio" name="q1" />${choice}</span>`
).join('<br />');

document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = htmlOfChoices
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function which creates a new `radio` button giving `name`,`value` and `text`.

```
function makeRadioButton(name, value, text) {
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    var radio = document.createElement("input");
    radio.type = "radio";
    radio.name = name;
    radio.value = value;
    label.appendChild(radio);
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    return label;
}
```

For iterating all `choices` options, you can use `forEach` method, which accepts as parameter a `callback` function.

```js
function makeRadioButton(name, value, text) {
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    var radio = document.createElement("input");
    radio.type = "radio";
    radio.name = name;
    radio.value = value;
    label.appendChild(radio);
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    return label;
  }

function Question(q, choices, answer) {
        this.question = q;
        this.choices = choices;
        this.correctAnswer = answer;
} 
var ques1 = new Question("What is the capital of PA?", "Erie,Pittsburgh,Harrisburg","Harrisburg");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ques1.question;
ques1.choices.split(',').forEach(function(item){
    var radio=makeRadioButton("ques1",item,item);
    document.getElementById("demo2").appendChild(radio);
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <body>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <p id="demo2"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're sending all the choices as 1 string.
You should consider using a data structure so you could iterate over them, perhaps something along the lines:

```
var choices = ["Erie","Pittsburgh","Harrisburg"]     //choices is an array
Question("What is the capital of PA?",choices ,choices[2]);  //choices[2] is 'Harrisburg' as a string.
```

you can then go over the array like so:

```
for (i = 0; i < choices .length; i++) { 
    console.log(choices[i]);
}
```

You can also just send the number instead of the answer, e.g.-

```
Question("What is the capital of PA?",choices ,2);
```

Then just go `choices[answer]` to get the string of the answer.

Hope that helps